# PostgreSQL pivot table with CASE WHEN Clause

Tags: database, postgresql

I have the following table in PostgreSQL called `tbl_sampleTime`:

```
====================================
   Date         Time        Temp
====================================
2016-11-01      15:00        25     
2016-11-01      07:00        21      
2016-11-01      23:00        14  
2016-11-01      17:00        19      
2016-11-01      09:00        13 
2016-11-01      01:00        13
2016-11-01      03:00        12
2016-11-01      11:00        23 
2016-11-01      19:00        19 
2016-11-01      13:00        27    
2016-11-01      21:00        18    
2016-11-01      05:00        13
```

I would like to create a query using CASE WHEN to return the following pivot:

```
===================================================================================================
    Date      ||      Time I   Temp I   ||      Time II   Temp II   ||     Time III   Temp III   
===================================================================================================
  2016-11-01  ||      07.00      21     ||      15.00       25      ||     23.00        14   
  2016-11-01  ||      09.00      13     ||      17.00       19      ||     01.00        13 
  2016-11-01  ||      11.00      23     ||      19.00       19      ||     03.00        12   
  2016-11-01  ||      13.00      27     ||      21.00       18      ||     05.00        13
```

Is it possible to do it without Crosstab but just using CASE WHEN clause ?

Comment: What type is the `Time` column?  What is the rule for dividing up the data from a single date across three columns?  What would happen if there were other dates which did not have 12 data points?  Etc...

Comment: why dont want use crosstab?

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen Time column is a `varchar`. Btw, all data always and only have 12 data points, date 1 (12 data), date 2 (12 data) and so on..

Comment: You shouldn't store date/time data as `varchar` _ever_, because, as you're seeing now, it makes it difficult to work with that data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this :

```
select "Date",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='00:00' then"Temp" else null end) "00",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='01:00' then"Temp" else null end) "01",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='02:00' then"Temp" else null end) "02",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='03:00' then"Temp" else null end) "03",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='04:00' then"Temp" else null end) "04",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='05:00' then"Temp" else null end) "05",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='06:00' then"Temp" else null end) "06",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='07:00' then"Temp" else null end) "07",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='08:00' then"Temp" else null end) "08",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='09:00' then"Temp" else null end) "09",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='10:00' then"Temp" else null end) "10",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='11:00' then"Temp" else null end) "11",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='12:00' then"Temp" else null end) "12",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='13:00' then"Temp" else null end) "13",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='14:00' then"Temp" else null end) "14",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='15:00' then"Temp" else null end) "15",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='16:00' then"Temp" else null end) "16",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='17:00' then"Temp" else null end) "17",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='18:00' then"Temp" else null end) "18",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='19:00' then"Temp" else null end) "19",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='20:00' then"Temp" else null end) "20",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='21:00' then"Temp" else null end) "21",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='22:00' then"Temp" else null end) "22",
   max(CASE WHEN "Time"='23:00' then"Temp" else null end) "23"
 from tbl_sampleTime group by "Date"
```

Comment: @remy-baron your query only result 1 row, `group by "Date"` merged to 1 Date for each date. I need a result like my above result

Answer (score 0):

I have explained in comments how its work. I have seperated time values into to groups and also numbered them within the group. first `LATERAL` join get second time values and second `LATERAL` join get third time values from the grouped time values.

```
with datas as (
select t._date,
       t._time,
       t._temp,
       --creating groups for pivot
       case
         when _time between '07:00:00'::TIME and '13:00:00'::TIME then 1
         when _time between '15:00:00'::TIME and '21:00:00'::TIME then 2
         else 3
       end as grps,
       --numbering each group to create pivot table
       row_number() over(PARTITION by 
        case
          when _time between '07:00:00'::TIME and '13:00:00'::TIME then 1
          when _time between '15:00:00'::TIME and '21:00:00'::TIME then 2
          else 3
        end order by _time - INTERVAL '7 hour'
        ) as rn
from table1 t
order by _time - INTERVAL '7 hour' --ordered for starting with '07:00' o'clock
)
select s1._date as "Date",
       s1._time as "TIME I",
       s1._temp as "TEMP I",
       _second.*,
       _third.*
from
--starting with first group to build our pivot table
(
select *
from datas s
where grps=1
order by grps,_time
) s1,
     LATERAL
     (
       select s2._time as "TIME II",
              s2._temp as "TEMP II"
       from datas s2
       where s2.rn=s1.rn and --exact number of each group
             s2.grps = s1.grps + 1 --to get second value
     ) _second,
     LATERAL
     (
       select s3._time as "TIME III",
              s3._temp as "TEMP III"
       from datas s3
       where s3.rn=s1.rn and --exact number of each group
             s3.grps = s1.grps + 2 --to get third value
     ) _third --on true;
```